# How to replace two values in a matrix in place of each other in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix in Matlab similar to this example,

```
X = [0.5+0.5i 0.5-0.5i 0;
      0.5+0.5i 0 0.2+0.4i;
      0     0.2+0.1i 0]
```

What I need to do is to replace all values of `0.5+0.5i` to be `0`, and replace all values of `0` to be `0.5+0.5i`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that your goal is to interchange all appearances of values `a` and `b` in the matrix.

Two ways to do this:

1. Directly manipulating the matrix:

   1. Replace value `a` in the array by some sentinel value `z`. (It's important that you are 100% sure the value `z` will never appear in the matrix. For example, maybe Inf or -Inf)
   2. Replace value `b` in the array by `a`.
   3. Replace value `z` in the array by `b`.

```
a = 0.5+0.5i;
b = 0;
z = Inf;
X(X==a) = z;
X(X==b) = a;
X(X==z) = b;
```

2. If you cannot safely find a sentinel value `z`, then you will need to keep track of the indices in the array that correspond to values `a` and `b`:

```
a = 0.5+0.5i;
b = 0;
ia = find(X==a);
ib = find(X==b);
X(ia) = b;
X(ib) = a;
```

---

**Word of caution**: when finding non-integer numbers, make sure you take into account of floating-point errors. If you computed 0.50000001 from an earlier computation, MATLAB will not see this as 0.5.

Comment: Even though it is mentioned in the answer, comparing floating-point numbers using logical equality operator like `X==a` is a big no-no. Just don't do it. Instead use comparison to a suitably small number such as `(X-a) < eps`, or in your case, `(abs(real(X)-0.5) < eps) & (abs(imag(X)-0.5) < eps)`.

Comment: In more explicit terms: `eps = 1e-6; ia = find(abs(X-a) < eps); X(ia) = b;` We can apply floating point error to the entire imaginary number (as in this example here), or apply it separately on the real/imaginary parts as suggested by Kavka. Technically, the latter is the right way to treat floating-point errors, but the loss of accuracy in the former is usually negligible in most applications.`eps` can also be set a lot smaller: 1e-6 is just a number I typically use for practical purposes.